# How do I install iptables-translate?

Tags: firewall, iptables, nftables

I'm on a CentOS 7 machine. I'd like to try the use of [nftables](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page). Many sites reference [iptables-translate](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xtables-translate.8.html) as a helpful tool for translating from iptables to nftables rules. I've installed the `nftables.x86_64` package and have the `nft` command, but I don't have iptables-translate:

```
$ iptables-translate --help
-bash: iptables-translate: command not found
```

A yum search for `iptables-translate` and `xtables-translate` turns up nothing. How do I install this tool?

Answer (score 0):

`iptables-translate` is packaged with newer `iptables` version. CentOS 8 comes with iptables-1.8.x which has `iptables-translate`.

```
[root@ed766839cb33 dnf]# dnf whatprovides iptables-translate
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:19 ago on Fri Oct  9 21:43:38 2020.
iptables-1.8.4-10.el8_2.1.i686 : Tools for managing Linux kernel packet filtering capabilities
Repo        : BaseOS
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/iptables-translate

iptables-1.8.4-10.el8_2.1.x86_64 : Tools for managing Linux kernel packet filtering capabilities
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/iptables-translate

iptables-1.8.4-10.el8_2.1.x86_64 : Tools for managing Linux kernel packet filtering capabilities
Repo        : BaseOS
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/iptables-translate
```